# How to stop a video using stop function?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

Alright, I have very little programming experience and just want to make controls for video and audio pieces together on one page. I have searched a lot and can't figure it out.

```
var stop = function (id) {
    .pause();
    .src = '';
};
```

I want to pass either the audio or videos' id as the parameter in my function but I don't understand how make code that can be used with either. I can't put id.pause(); into my function to pause whatever id I put in as a parameter, so I'm confused as to how to make it work. Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JQuery:

```
$('#playMovie1').click(function(){
  $('#movie1').get(0).play();
      });
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
function playVid(x) { 
   var vid = document.getElementById(x).pause();  
}
```

Comment: If `jQuery` is not tagged, why to use it in solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var stop = function (htmlId) {
    var vid = document.getElementById(htmlId); 

    vid.pause();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! So I have to create a new variable in every function to do this?

Comment: Im not sure but you can try to use  "document.getElementById(htmlId).pause();" instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the id then use that id to pause or play

```
var stop = function (id) {
    $('#'+id).pause(); // to pause the video
   .src = '';
};
```

Comment: If `jQuery` is not tagged, why to use it in solution ?